# Altering the backlight dim timeout on a Thinkpad laptop

Tags: thinkpad, backlight

It seems something else than `gnome-power-manager` manages the backlight dim timeout on Thinkpads, maybe `thinkpad-acpi`.

How do you alter the timeout from 5 seconds? (which is very annoying)

Comment: The display driver might take a role in here. What display driver are you using?

Comment: The official nvidia one. I remember having much trouble about the display driver in the beginning.

Comment: Can't say for nvidia. The Radeon Catalyst Control Panel has an option "Vari-Bright" that, when enabled, produces the behavior you described.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue on a Thinkpad x220. The following message showed up in */var/log/dmesg*:

> [   10.262915] thinkpad_acpi: Standard ACPI backlight interface
>   available, not loading native one

You can tell linux to let a vendor specific driver (thinkpad_acpi) handle the backlight by passing the acpi_backlight=vendor option to the kernel.

To do this:

1. Edit `/etc/default/grub`
2. Add `acpi_backlight=vendor` to the list of options in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`
3. Run `sudo update-grub`

The backlight is now managed by thinkpad_acpi and does not dim after 5 secs.

Comment: Works for me (Ubuntu 15.04, T430). Thanks!